# Getting access to all the machines in a data center through one command or series of commands

Tags: linux, database, unix, networking

I was recently interviewed at some big software company for the post of database engineer for their web services center. The interviewer asked me a question which was like: "if you were to access all the computers or the machines in our data center through a computer, then how can you do that?"
and he also asked, "if your disk is full and you find out the file which is responsible for that, you delete it but it still shows up that the disk is full. What is the reason for that?" well i didn't know the answer for the two questions so can anybody explain the answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a file delete, many user interfaces move the file to a "recycling" directory instead of actually deleting it.  Usually some special user action is needed to directly delete it, as well as delete it from recycling.

Even for an actual file delete, it may be several seconds to minutes for the relevant part of the filesystem to recognize it has increased free space, especially for a very large file.

---

The question about access to all the computers appears to be a trick question.  "If you were to access all the computers..." means it was accomplished.  The appropriate finish is "... how might you have done it?"  There are many ways which come to mind:

- Walk in and gain physical access.
- Login to all the systems.
- Write a program which accesses all the systems, perhaps as web servers or database servers, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, is there anything called "Screenshots" which are continuously stored into the memory of the disk and we are to delete them as well?? and if there are many machines in a data center, will it be physically possible to log into each and everyone?As the interviewer laid stress on gaining control from one computer only...

Comment: re multi-machine access. There is at least one utility I have seen used where you can login to many machines at once and execute the same command line sequence on all of them. But I can't remember the name. Might be related to `ssh`. Good luck.